# Outbound SSL connection from Node

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I am trying to connect from Node to a server that is using SSL.  The connection works when I connect to a test server, but not the live server I need to connect to.

Does anyone know if Node requires some sort of configuration to support outbound connections?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried about 15 different permutations so posting the code would be difficult.  I'm sorry, but I cannot provide URLs to the servers for confidentiality.

Comment: I am researching it, but this post may be the answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507878/ssl-connection-reset)  The issue in that question is that Java is not negotiating SSL versions correctly.  This pull request for node deals with the same thing: [link](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/873)

Comment: The issue appears to be that the TLS implementation in node is not properly negotiating the TLS version being used by the server that I cannot connect to.  The server that works supports SSLv2, but the server that is failing does not support SSLv2 and only supports a handful of SSLv3 ciphers.  So when node goes to negotiate to find the correct cipher, it either dies or the remote server stops responding because of too many failed attempts.  I found that since 0.4, node supports a way to not even try SSLv2, but I cannot find the setting that controls it.  Does anyone know how to set this?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded node to 0.8 and this started working.