# Connection reset error when downloading file from HTTPS location

Tags: java, exception, https

I have a java program as to download file from https location. It is comnecting through proxy. It is downloading file from two locations as mentioned below

```
1. https://www.treasury.gov/ofac/downloads/sdn.xml
2. https://www.un.org/sc/suborg/sites/www.un.org.sc.suborg/files/1267.xml
```

The code was working fine but suddenly while downloading 2nd URL it is failing with below error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Yitm.png)
I have searched a lot but found no clue why it is failing as it is fine for 1st URL which is also HTTPS.
The code is using standard HTTPUrlConnection.Below is snippet
[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsay2.png)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/5508435/643500

Comment: I tried adding the property System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3"); in my code but it still gives the same error :(