# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset error when calling Azure Maps service from Azure databricks

Tags: scala, azure, https, azure-databricks, azure-maps

We have a resource group which contains Azure Databricks service and Azure Maps Account. 
The goal is to call Azure Maps [endpoints related to Geo coding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-search-for-address#request-latitude-and-longitude-for-an-address-geocoding). For some reason, I keep on receiving

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

no matter the very same request executes successfully via Postman. 
[image]

In order to prepare my HTTP request for Scala (the language that I use in my Databricks notebook) I use [this](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http) library/package. So, the notebook content looks something like this:

```
val response: HttpResponse[String] = Http("https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/json?subscription-key=my_key&api-version=1.0&query=my_query_str")
.option(HttpOptions.connTimeout(10000)).asString
//.timeout(connTimeoutMs = 100000, readTimeoutMs = 500000).asString

response.code
```

and then, the detailed error looks like this:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.setNewClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:100)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.setNewClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:80)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:706)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1591)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:92)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1490)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1488)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:784)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1487)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
    at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.scalaj$http$HttpRequest$$doConnection(Http.scala:367)
    at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.exec(Http.scala:343)
    at scalaj.http.HttpRequest.asString(Http.scala:492)
    at lined047365c6afd4053bf68147e840c60bb25.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3596544709550112:4)
    at lined047365c6afd4053bf68147e840c60bb25.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3596544709550112:55)
    at lined047365c6afd4053bf68147e840c60bb25.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3596544709550112:57)
    at lined047365c6afd4053bf68147e840c60bb25.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3596544709550112:59)
    at lined047365c6afd4053bf68147e840c60bb25.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(command-3596544709550112:61)
    at lined047365c6afd4053bf68147e840c60bb25.$read$$iw.<init>(command-3596544709550112:63)
    at lined047365c6afd4053bf68147e840c60bb25.$read.<init>(command-3596544709550112:65)
    at lined047365c6afd4053bf68147e840c60bb25.$read$.<init>(command-3596544709550112:69)
    at lined047365c6afd4053bf68147e840c60bb25.$read$.<clinit>(command-3596544709550112)
    at lined047365c6afd4053bf68147e840c60bb25.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<notebook>:7)
    at lined047365c6afd4053bf68147e840c60bb25.$eval$.$print(<notebook>:6)
    at lined047365c6afd4053bf68147e840c60bb25.$eval.$print(<notebook>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:793)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1054)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:645)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:644)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:576)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:572)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverILoop.execute(DriverILoop.scala:215)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal$$anonfun$repl$1.apply(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:699)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExit$.apply(DriverLocal.scala:652)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ScalaDriverLocal.repl(ScalaDriverLocal.scala:202)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:385)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$$anonfun$execute$9.apply(DriverLocal.scala:362)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:251)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:246)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:288)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:49)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:362)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper$$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$2.apply(DriverWrapper.scala:644)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:639)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:485)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:597)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:390)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:337)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:219)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**UPDATE**: No matter if we have a valid shared key in the URL or not, the error is still the same:
    https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/json?subscription-key=**my_key**&api-version=1.0&query=my_query_str

Comment: I don't believe this is an issue with Azure Maps, but perhaps has something to do with the implementation. Looking into this error, it appears a common reason for it is closing the connection before the response has been completely read.

Note the response will be JSON, in case that changes anything with that library.

Comment: @rbrundritt Yes, it definitely is not an Azure Maps issue but rather Databricks to Azure Maps issue. For some reason, the connection gets closed before response was received. I have updated my question with some further observations.

Comment: Came across this, it looked similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507878/ssl-connection-reset

Comment: @user2128702 is your issue solved? Please post the solution as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @asergaz not really.