# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset exception when connecting DocuSign development endpoint

Tags: docusignapi

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset

I'm trying to connect **Docusign's development endpoint (account-d.docusign.com)** through my application. We are experiencing "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset" when the application tries to retrieve a JWT user token using **"requestJWTUserToken"** method. What might be causing the SSL exception? Thanks for any help!

Comment: probably duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507878/ssl-connection-reset Could also be a problem with outdated certs in your machine, but the error should be different then.

Comment: @HEllRZA _very_ unlikely. Java 7, released just months affter that Q, stopped doing SSLv2Hello, and the answer there absolutely won't work because SSLv3 was completely broken by 'POODLE' in 2014 and all systems including Java quickly prohibited it. OP: to try to narrow it down get a log from sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` (add `:keymanager` if you are using a client cert). Also, how are you connected to the Internet, and does that name resolve to 64.207.216.101 or 102 for you?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085
Token is generating when connecting DocuSign from a standalone application locally but getting "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset" issue when trying to get a token from application deployed in Docker.

Comment: @docusignapi Token is generating when connecting DocuSign from a standalone application locally but getting "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset" issue when trying to get a token from application deployed in Docker

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the connection has been closed by the server end of the connection. This could be an issue with the request you are sending

To aid debugging you could look at using a tool such as Wireshark to view the actual network packets.
The cause could be that the connection inside HttpClient is stale. Check stale connection for SSL does not fix this error. Solution: dump your client and recreate.

Comment: Token is generating when connecting DocuSign from a standalone application locally but getting "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset" issue when trying to get a token from application deployed in Docker.